# NSIS ExecDos plug-in doesn't work with latest (>=3.07) makensis.exe

Tags: nsis, makensis

[ExecDos](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/ExecDos_plug-in) plug-in don't work with latest (>=3.07) `makensis.exe`.

`ExecDos:exec` immediately returns with strange error code.

Answer (score 0):

That can happen because of "breaking" change in `makensis` version [3.07](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Docs/AppendixF.html#v3.07-cl):

> F.3.2.1 Major Changes
> [Unicode](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Docs/Chapter4.html#aunicodetarget) now defaults to true

So, if your script and `ExecDos.dll` are non-Unicode, you should explicitly set it by adding `Unicode false` line (at the beginning of nsi file).

Comment: ...and NSIS 3 has been emitting a warning about a coming change to Unicode for the last 3 years before this.

Comment: That's great. But I started to work with NSIS only one week ago (on this one: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-packaging/pull/15) and nothing prepared me to this failure. And this question on stackoverflow could save me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

The ExecDos plug-in has both ANSI and Unicode versions included in its .zip, make sure you are using the correct version. This is really important if you are using `!addplugindir`.